# Use array_position with JPA Criteria API?

Tags: hibernate, function, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

I am using springjpa & postgresql,there is a field in my database which is bitint array type,And in Java,it is a Long value.

I am using spring jpa CriteriaBuilder&Specification to make a array position function :

```
private Predicate toPredicate(String propName, Query q, Root<T> root, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
    ...
    return cb.isNotNull(cb.function("array_position", Integer.class,
                            xx expression,
                            cb.literal(q.value)));  // q.value is a long type value
}
```

And it goes error when i execution query:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        distinct ruletemp0_.id as id1_119_,
        ruletemp0_.applicant as applican2_119_,
        ruletemp0_.approver as approver3_119_,
        ruletemp0_.devices as devices4_119_,
        ruletemp0_.end_time as end_time5_119_,
        ruletemp0_.execution_id as executio6_119_,
        ruletemp0_.execution_type as executio7_119_,
        ruletemp0_.extra as extra8_119_,
        ruletemp0_.rule_id as rule_id9_119_,
        ruletemp0_.start_time as start_t10_119_,
        ruletemp0_.state as state11_119_,
        ruletemp0_.user_id as user_id12_119_ 
    from
        tbl_ruletemp ruletemp0_ 
    where
        array_position(ruletemp0_.user_id, 1) is not null 
        or array_position(ruletemp0_.user_id, 2) is not null
2019-10-30 10:44:42.230 [WARN ] [main] [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper::logExceptions] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883
2019-10-30 10:44:42.230 [ERROR] [main] [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper::logExceptions] ERROR: function array_position(bigint[], integer) does not exist
  建议：No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

It seems jpa does not recognize my Long type value,i try to use:

```
BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(q.value));
return cb.isNotNull(cb.function("array_position", Integer.class,
                            toExpression(propName, root),
                            cb.literal(bigInteger)));
```

Still error.
If i execute SQL query in pg directly :

```
select * from tbl_ruletemp t where array_position(t.user_id, cast(1 as BIGINT)) is not null;
```

will work.

And ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `cast` expression with the criteria builder, but it may not be necessary. Instead of using the number as a literal, pass it as a parameter.

```
ParameterExpression<BigInteger> pid = cb.parameter(BigInteger.class, "pid");
return cb.isNotNull(cb.function("array_position", Integer.class,
                            toExpression(propName, root),
                            pid));
```

Then simply bind the parameter as you normally would. And since you're using arrays, perhaps it would be better to use `arrayoverlap` instead of chaining `array_position` calls and `or` expressions.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you be more clear?How to bind my value with ParameterExpression.

Comment: Once you have the query created with `entityManager.createQuery` you call `setParameter("pid", bigIntValue)` on it.